# map yaml config to a java hashmap

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I have below in my yaml

```
endpointWithType: {abc: 'POST', def: 'GET'}
```

I am map it in my spring bean as follow,

```
@Value("#{'${endpointWithType}'}")
Map<String,String> endpointWithType;
```

I get below error,

> Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
> [java.util.Map]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

How can I map a configuration map representation to a java hashmap?

Comment: try this `@Value("#{${endpointWithType}}")`

Comment: That isn't yaml, that is half-arsed YAML with JSON. A map in YAML needs to have seperate key/values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yaml try to format it in this way:

```
endpointWithType:
  abc: POST
  def: GET
```

Or try this way:

```
endpointWithType: '{abc: "POST", def: "GET"}'
```

```
@Value("#{${endpointWithType}}")
private Map<String, String> endpointWithType;
```

Comment: First way gave me this error: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'. But second way worked